# Subdomain e-mail query

Tags: domain-name-system, email

Can someone confirm a query for me – we have separate sub domains set up in as separate mail domain accounts. How should we compile our DNS to facilitate this?

I will try and simplify this a little, so in our admin console we have –

---

Domain.com |
                Users -
                                info@domain.com |
                Groups

---

Sub.domain.com |
                Users -
                                john@sub.domain.com |
                Groups

---

Sub2.domain.com |
                Users - 
                                ann@sub2.domain.com |
                Groups

---

How should we setup this up correctly in DNS? Should we setup independent DNS zone files (for domain, sub.domain, and sub2.domain) or can each MX record be stated under the domain.com zone file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your DNS server, but the general idea is to create a subdomain zone (subordinate or separate) and assign the NS, MX, and default A records to it just like you did for domain.com.

Comment: Many thanks Hyppy, I will try creating separate DNS zone files for sub.domain and sub2.domain (independent from domain.com) and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do seperate mx records for the sub domains, see below for the MX in your example, Assuming each subdomain has a seperate mail server I set the a records up for 3 mail servers

@ IN MX 10 mail
subdmain1 IN MX 10 mail2
subdomain2 IN MX mail3

mail IN A 27.32.25.10 (Mail server for main domain)
mail2 IN A 21.65.54.97 (mail server for subsomain 1)
mail3 IN A 21.65.54.247 (mail server for subsomain 2)